# HTML - When Header Is Hovered, It Changes Pic In Another Div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, onhover

I have been trying to figure this out, but so far nothing has worked for me.  I am currently using Wordpress.  I have several elements within one div.  The header h6 element is within a div itself, and the background-image element is also within a div, which it has an image and on hover the image changes color (aka changes to another image same size and etc. but different color).  What I am trying to do is, when someone hovers over the header h6 element/title, it will also trigger the image to change to the other image.  My current code is below...

```
<style>
.myButtonClient {
  display: block;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background: url('clients-white-e1472751653800.png') bottom;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}
.myButtonClient:hover {
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background: url('clients-blue-e1472751683604.png') bottom;
}
.info_header {  
  text-decoration: none !important; 
  color:#396ba5;
}
.info_header:hover {color:#222222;}
.benefit_header {   
  text-decoration: none !important; 
  color:#ffffff !important;
}
.benefit_header:hover {color:#222222;}
</style>


<div style="width: 98%; float: left; clear: both;">
     <div id="one" style="width: 20%; float: left;"><a class="myButtonClient" href="#">client</a></div>
     <div style="width: 80%; float: left;">
         <h6 style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Century Gothic',CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; font-weight: bolder; text-align: left; margin-top: 2px;"><a class="info_header" href="#">Client Lookup</a></h6>
         <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; width: 100%; height: 10px; margin-top: -45px; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
         <p style="font-size: 10px; font-family: 'Century Gothic',CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; font-weight: bolder; text-align: left; margin-top: -20px;">Search and obtain client information. Any where from archives, contract to notes. Usu illud etiam mentitum an, at choro regione pericula sed.</p>

     </div>
 </div>
```

So, when the title is hover the title will change color to #222222, and the image in another div will change to the secondary image.  My attention is to make multiple of these on one page, like a list.  I tried putting the a href surrounding the divs, changing the background image but the background image keeps messing up and etc.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: javascript can fix this, can you use that?

Comment: It might be possible.  We can definitely give it a try.

Comment: but prefer to use css cause right now there is already too much jquery on the page.